# Filtering generic collection while comparing with another collection

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, filtering

I have to do some filtering in a generic collection. I am trying to use LINQ for that. Here is my code:

```
from student in students
where student.ID == (Here is another collection) from newstudent in Newstudents
select newstudent.ID
select student
```

I don't know how to compare int collection with single int. Please tell me a good way to do it.

Comment: Well what comparison are you trying to perform? Are you trying to find all students with an ID in that collection? If so, you could use `Contains`, e.g. `where ids.Contains(student.ID)`... or you could use a join against the collection.

Comment: you an also use join for this if you are having two collection

Comment: How I use Contains. I am unable to. I have updated code. Please take another look at what I am trying to do

Answer (score 1):

For fast lookup first put the student id's in a `HashSet`. The use `Contains` on that for checking existence of the id.

```
var studentIds = new HashSet<int>(newStudents.Select(x => x.ID));
var filtered = students.Where(x => studentIds.Contains(x.ID));
```